# Need WMI query to get the dll information from Windows

Tags: windows, dll, wmi, .net-assembly

Need WMI query to get the assmebly file details udner the path: 
*C:\Windows\Assembly\GAC_MSIL*

I want to monitor this path once in a day and get information on:
1.Assembly Name
2.Date created
3.Date Modified
4.Full Name
5.Public Key Token

I **don't want PowerShell** Script to get these details. I Need a WMI query.

**More information:**

I used the WMI query: "SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile " but this doesnt work . Displays Description: "Invalid Class" .
Please let me know the correct class name, namespace

Many Thanks,
Simbu

Answer (score 0):

The right way of using CIM_DataFile is this:

```
"SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive ='C:' AND Path='\\Demo\\' AND FileName='u' AND Extension='dll'"
```

But, I don't think this will give you PublicKey Token.